# Can we trigger Azure Pipeline after completion of other pipeline for any tag?

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

Is there a way that we can trigger pipeline after another pipeline when triggering pipeline build on any existing/new tags?
like following:

```
resources:
  pipelines:    
  - pipeline: name1
    source: pipeline1
    trigger: 
      branches:
        include: 
        - master
      tags:
        - '*'
```

This is failing with
`Tags set for trigger didn't match any pipeline.`

I know we can add wild character with some character as prefix, something like

```
tags:
   - 'tag*'
```

But in my repo tag naming convention is not consistent. which starts with numeric/any character.

I Looked here, but no luck yet.

https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-yaml/blob/master/design/pipeline-triggers.md

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/pipeline-triggers?view=azure-devops

Comment: Try to change the tags character as below

    tags:
    - 'tags.*'

Comment: @SaiSakethGuduru-MT
 Its not triggering the pipeline with error: `Tags set for trigger doesn't match the pipeline`. so, as I said there is no tag with prefix as `tags` all are something like 0.1.2, 2.3.4 ,..so on. even some starts with some name as well. will this be an issue here?

Comment: it should be something like this # specific tag
   trigger:
      tags:
        include:
        - v2.*
        exclude:
        - v2.0

Comment: Actually, this works. but my requirement was triggering based on any naming convention for tags. something like '*'.

Comment: As far as I know we can't use naming convention for tags